# Simple probability on random binary generator

Tags: probability

Just want to check the answer.

The below is the question:

A random binary machine produces number '0' 20% of the time and number '1' 80% of the time. What is the probability of getting 2 '0' and 2 '1'?

My answer is 0.2*0.2*0.8*0.8 = 0.0256

Is the answer correct? Thanks!

Comment: Think of $4$ experiments that can succeed or fail. If a number $1$ is labeled as "succes" then $p=0.8$ is the chance on succes. You are asked to find $P(X=2)$ where $X$ denotes the number of successes. This under binomial distribution with parameters $n=4$ and $p=0.8$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not correct. If you perform the same experiment independently $4$ times, the probability that you will obtain two $0$'s and two $1$'s is given by
$$
\binom 4 2  0.2^20.8^2=0.1536.
$$
See the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

$0.0256$ is the probability of having the exact $0011$ sequence.

The probability of having two $0$ and two $1$ in any order would be $$0.2\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 6 = 0.1536$$

You have to multiply it by $6$ because there are 6 possible arrays with two $0$ and two $1$.

Answer (score 0):

These are the probabilities of each one of the desired sequences:

- $P(0011)=0.2\times0.2\times0.8\times0.8=0.0256$
- $P(0101)=0.2\times0.8\times0.2\times0.8=0.0256$
- $P(0110)=0.2\times0.8\times0.8\times0.2=0.0256$
- $P(1001)=0.8\times0.2\times0.2\times0.8=0.0256$
- $P(1010)=0.8\times0.2\times0.8\times0.2=0.0256$
- $P(1100)=0.8\times0.8\times0.2\times0.2=0.0256$

There are $6$ such sequences, hence the overall probability is $6\times0.0256=0.1536$.